# Is there any way to expose Sitecore Api? So that 3rd party application can use POST request and further sitecore application can manage POST request

Tags: sitecore-api

I have 3rd party application, and I want to send some data to sitecore application using POST method. So is it possible to handle HTTP POST within sitecore MVC ? If yes please suggest how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it by creating an `API controller`. So for this you need to follow these steps.

- Create a controller and inherit it from `ApiController`

  ```
  namespace Feature.ExampleApi.Controllers
  {
     public class ExampleApiController : ApiController
     {
       [HttpPost]
       [Route("post/{itemNameString}")]
       public IHttpActionResult CreateItem(string itemNameString)
       {
           // Do your operation

           // Do sth with item

           return Json(result);
       }
    }
  }
  ```
- Register your controller

  ```
  namespace Feature.ExampleApi
  {
     public class ServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
     {
       public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
       {
           // Controllers
           serviceCollection.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(ExampleApiController),
               typeof(ExampleApiController)));
       }
    }
  }
  ```

  If you are working with headless environment, register it like this.

  ```
  public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
  {
      serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDefaultRenderingContentsResolver, DefaultRenderingContentsResolver>();
      serviceCollection.AddMvcControllers("*.Feature");
  }
  ```

  Follow this article for headless environment.

  https://trnktms.com/2022/09/29/sitecore-headless-how-to-reuse-layout-service-serialization-in-custom-api-controllers/
- Create config.

  ```
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
      <services>
       <configurator type="Feature.ExampleApi.ServicesConfigurator, Feature.ExampleApi" />
      </services>
    </sitecore>
  </configuration>
  ```

Follow this article for more details.

https://jakubwajs.wordpress.com/2020/06/21/create-api-controller-in-sitecore-9-3/

You can also work with the Sitecore Item Serice to create items and more.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting error while registering controller in DI (error code CS0012) I'm using framework 4.6 with sitecore 10 (headless).

Comment: @Ranjeet If you are working with headless, you can try this approach. https://trnktms.com/2022/09/29/sitecore-headless-how-to-reuse-layout-service-serialization-in-custom-api-controllers/

Comment: @Ranjeet Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: yes I'm working with headless. And i want to use HTTP POST api method within sitecore, so that i can expose api to 3rd party and get data from 3rd party tool via Sitecore api. As I'm new in sitecore so please help me out with an example.

Comment: @Ranjeet Did you check the article that I shared in the comments?

Comment: Yes, i have checked but in that article HTTP GET is used to expose JSON (Like layout service).
I want to use HTTP POST to receive some data from other 3rd party tool. Can i use the same way as given for HTTP GET ?

Comment: Yes you can do it the same way.

Comment: Thanks, Its working now. I have inherited "SitecoreController" instead of "ApiController".